# Dropout_U and Dropout_W is not defined in LSTM model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, sentiment-analysis

I am facing this error

```
NameError: name 'Dropout_U' is not defined
```

by creating an LSTM model

```
embed_dim = 128
lstm_out = 200
batch_size = 32

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(2500, embed_dim,input_length = X.shape[1]))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(lstm_out))
model.add(Dropout_U(0.2))
model.add(Dropout_W(0.2))
model.add(Dense(2,activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics = ['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
```

Can you help me overcome this problem?

Comment: What is `Dropout_U` and `Dropout_W` ?

Comment: dropout_U: float between 0 and 1. Fraction of the input units to drop for recurrent connections.    dropout_W: float between 0 and 1. Fraction of the input units to drop for input gates.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax used is outdated, `Dropout_U` has been changed to `recurrent_dropout`. `Dropout_W` is simply `Dropout`.

If you replace `Dropout_U` with `recurrent_dropout` and make it part of your LSTM layer it should work. Simply change the `Dropout_W` layer to `Dropout`.

```
embed_dim = 128
lstm_out = 200
batch_size = 32

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(2500, embed_dim,input_length = X.shape[1]))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(lstm_out, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(2,activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics = ['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
```